# Find order of $xy$ provided $x^2=e, y^3=e$ and $yxy=xy^2x$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $x,y \in G$.  Suppose $x^2=e$, $y^3=e$ and $yxy=xy^2x$. Find the order of $xy$.

I have no idea what to do. I am suspecting $(xy)^6=e$ (order 6) but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: $(xy)^6 = e$ isn't necessarily true. If the group is abelian, then $(xy)^6 = x^6y^6 = e$.

Comment: $(xy)^2=xyxy=x^2y^2x=y^2x$.  Try working out the next few...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, look at the successive powers of $xy$ and try to simplify.  Here, we have:
$$
xy\\
(xy)^2=xyxy=x(yxy)=x(xy^2 x)=x^2y^2x=y^2x\\
(xy)^3=xy(y^2x)=xy^3x=xx=e
$$
So, in fact, $(xy)^3=e$, which means that the order of $xy$ is (at most) $3$.

Comment: Hmm... it could be that $x=e=y$ too (in which case $xy=e$ has order $1$).  The question doesn't say e.g. "the order of $x$ is $2$".  [It must be a divisor of 3, though.  So it's either $3$ or $1$.]

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones: That's a fair point. I suppose that I presumed that the question meant to be as unrestrictive as possible, so that $x,y$ are non-identity elements such that etc. They also never say that $yxy=xy^2x$ is the only relator.

Comment: It's somewhat implicit that saying e.g. "$x^2=e$" implies $x$ has order $2$, otherwise we'd instead say "$x=e$" (or not even introduce $x$).  Perhaps I'm a bit too pedantic (but this kind of detail matters e.g. for automated theorem proving).  Anyway, the answer is fine so I better +1 it.

Comment: Yeah I meant the order of x is 2 and the order of y is 3. Thanks for the help. It seems so easy now but I couldn't find it myself.

Comment: blondy: Thank you for clarifying. @DouglasS.Stones: interesting point and the +1 is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $x^2=1$ and $y^3=1$. Then we have the following.
$$\begin{align*}
yxy&=xy^2x\\
\Rightarrow
xyxy&=y^2x\\
\Rightarrow
xyxyx&=y^2\\
\Rightarrow
xyxyxy&=y^3\\
\Rightarrow (xy)^3&=1
\end{align*}$$

This gives an upper bound. I will leave you to prove that this is, in fact, a lower bound (so long as there are no other relators). To get you started, consider a regular Tetrahedron, or equivalently the following graph.

$\hskip2in$[image: A graph with symmetries of the tetrahedron]

(Indeed, it seems there are precisely five groups with this property, and only two of these are such that $x\neq 1 \neq y$).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to organize the argument, though ultimately the same as user1729's answer: The first two equations tell you that $x=x^{-1}$ and $y^2=y^{-1}$. Plugging those into the third equation, you get $yxy=x^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1} =(xyx)^{-1}$. That is, $yxy$ is the inverse of $xyx$, meaning that their product (in either order) is $e$. So $xyxyxy=e$, which means that $xy$ has order $3$ or $1$.